# How to get filename, function, line, and column from Error for EntryLog.SourceLocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, winston

I am using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) logger with [EntryLog](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogEntrySourceLocation) spec for logging, and I wanna get these data from `new Error().stack`:

```
{
  file: "index.js",
  function: "getData",
  line: 20,
  column: 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out:

```
/**
 * Parses and returns info about the call stack.
 */
function getSouceLocation(error) {
  // get call stack, and analyze it and 
  // remove unnecessary stacktrace [node_modules, <anonymous>]
  // get all file, method, and line numbers
  const stacklist = error.stack
    .replace(/^.*[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*$|^.((?!at).)*$|^.*<anonymous>.*$|^.*internal\/timers.js.*$/gm, "")
    .replace(/\n+/g, "\n").split("\n")
    .filter((item, index, array) => {
      if (!!item) {
        return index === array.indexOf(item);
      }
    });

  // stack trace format:
  // http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi
  // do not remove the regex expresses to outside of this method (due to a BUG in node.js)
  var stackReg = /at\s+(.*)\s+\((.*):(\d*):(\d*)\)/gi
  var stackReg2 = /at\s+()(.*):(\d*):(\d*)/gi

  const sources = []
  stacklist.forEach((item) => {
    var sp = stackReg.exec(item) || stackReg2.exec(item)
    if (sp && sp.length === 5) {
      sources.push(
        {
          function: sp[1],
          file: path.relative(PROJECT_ROOT, sp[2]),
          line: sp[3],
          column: sp[4],
        }
      )
    }
  });
  const stack = stacklist.join('\n');
  return { sources, stack };
}
```

Result:

```
"sourceLocation": {
    "sources": [
      {
        "column": "36",
        "file": "src\\app\\controllers\\informasi\\panduan\\panduan-search.js",
        "function": "module.exports",
        "line": "11"
      },
      {
        "column": "7",
        "file": "src\\utils\\callback.js",
        "function": "",
        "line": "18"
      }
    ],
    "stack": "SequelizeDatabaseError: column a.nourutt does not exist\n    at module.exports (D:\\GOLANG\\gocode\\src\\github.com\\oss-rba\\back-portal\\src\\app\\controllers\\informasi\\panduan\\panduan-search.js:11:36)\n    at D:\\GOLANG\\gocode\\src\\github.com\\oss-rba\\back-portal\\src\\utils\\callback.js:18:7"
  },
```

Source: [winston logger with filename:linenumber](https://gist.github.com/transitive-bullshit/39a7edc77c422cbf8a18)